# How to build a Drag and Drop Menu Builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Hi all i present i am wokring on Menu Builder,where user can come build his menu how ever he likes with the subemnus to,i have a problem in Drag and Drop, i had done till drag but drop is not working in my case

i have to achevie some thing like this

http://www.prodevtips.com/demos/drag_drop_tree/

but not similar i should be able to create a chain or tree with drag and drop,my scenario is i have all menus listed at the bottom and and add column button at the top,when user wants to build menu he can click on addmenu button and a column opens there he can drag and drop the menus from the listed menu, from here i want the working scenario of the above link i had given where if i drop on any menu item it should be the child of that parent menu item which the user dropped on

here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("button[id='columnadd']").click(function () {
       alert(1);
       var domElement = $('<aside id="shoppingCart' + i + '" class="shoppingCart"><h2 class="ui-widget-header">Add Menu Items Here</h2><aside class="ui-widget-content"><ol><li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li></ol></aside></aside>');
       i++;
       $(this).after(domElement);
    });

    $(".small_box li" ).draggable({
       appendTo: "body",
       helper: "clone"
    });
});          

$(".small_box li a").droppable({
   tolerance        : "pointer",
   hoverClass        : "tree_hover",
   drop            : function(event, ui){
       var dropped = ui.draggable;
       dropped.css({top: 0, left: 0});
       var me = $(this).parent();
       if(me == dropped)
           return;
       var subbranch = $(me).children("ul");
       if(subbranch.size() == 0) {
           me.find("a").after("<ul></ul>");
           subbranch = me.find("ul");
       }
       var oldParent = dropped.parent();
       subbranch.eq(0).append(dropped);
       var oldBranches = $("li", oldParent);
       if (oldBranches.size() == 0) { $(oldParent).remove(); }
   }
});
```

and here is my html

```
<body>    
 <button id="columnadd" >Add Column</button>
 <aside class="menu-structer" id="AddColumns" >
  </aside>
 <aside class="small_box">
    <h4>BRANDS</h4>
    <ul>
        <li id ="brand1"><a class="" href="#">Brand1</a></li>
        <li id ="brand2"><a href="#">Brand2</a></li>
        <li id ="brand3"><a href="#">Brand3</a></li>
        <li id ="brand4"><a href="#">Brand4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
 <aside class="small_box">
    <h4>CATEGORIES</h4>
    <ul>
    <li id ="category1"><a href="#">Category1</a></li>
    <li id="category2"><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
    <li id="category3"><a href="#">Category3</a></li>
    <li id="category4"><a href="#">Category4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </aside>
 <aside class="small_box">
    <h4>PRODUCTS</h4>
    <ul>
    <li id="Product1"><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
    <li id="product2"><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
    <li id="product3"><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
    <li id="product4"><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </aside>
</body>
```

can any one help me over here please...that would be of a a great help for me..i am struggling with the Drop Event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakes i had done

I had  created a DOM Element (which is the drop area) upon click and this element is not in your page until you click the trigger. By doing `$('#shoppingCart ol').droppable({...})` in `$(document).ready(function() {})` block you try to add `droppable` to an element that even not in your page, so this won't do a thing.

changes

What i had done is make the element `droppable` **after**  create that element

```
$("button[id='columnadd']").click(function () {
  // create the element
  var domElement = $('<aside id="shoppingCart' + i++ + '" class="shoppingCart"><h2 class="ui-widget-header">Add Menu Items Here</h2><aside class="ui-widget-content" id="droppable"><ol><li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li></ol></aside></aside>');

  // put it after $(this)
  $(this).after(domElement);
  // at this point you have domElement in your page

  // make it droppable
  domElement.find("ol").droppable({
    // put options here
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      makeItDroppableToo(event, ui, this);
    }
  });
});
```

and this is the function to make your dropped element has its own placeholder

```
function makeItDroppableToo(e, ui, obj) {
  $(obj).find(".placeholder").remove();

  var placeholder = $("<ol><li class='placeholder'>You can also drop it here</li></ol>");
  $("<li></li>").append(ui.draggable.text()).append(placeholder).appendTo($(obj));

  // this is the same as the previous one
  placeholder.droppable({
    // put options here
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      makeItDroppableToo(event, ui, this);
    }
  });
}
```